# What verb tenses are commonly used in conversational English?

Tags: verbs, tenses

I have been learning the English language for five months. I have learned some basic verb tenses such as simple present, present continuous, simple past, past continuous, present perfect and present perfect continuous.

There are quite a few tenses that I haven't learned yet such as past perfect, past perfect continuous, future continuous, future perfect, future perfect continuous and future in the past.

I have spoken with some teachers and they told me that not all tenses are used in conversational English. I want to know which ones are commonly used in conversational English.

- Simple Present
- Present Continuous
- Simple Past
- Past Continuous
- Present Perfect
- Present Perfect Continuous
- Past Perfect
- Past Perfect Continuous
- Simple Future
- Future Continuous
- Future Perfect
- Future Perfect Continuous
- Future in the Past

Comment: Just out of interest, why are people voting to close this? The underlying premise may be false, but it's not such a bad question per se.

Comment: I think I use all of them except maybe the future perfect continuous, which doesn't come up very often. Which ones are most common would definitely be an interesting question.

Comment: The only verb form will only have ever had been used by me is the future perfect passive hortatory continuous...hold on, perfect -and- continuous? I thought 'perfect' meant 'completed'.

Comment: @Peter Shor: But OP *will have been hoping* for us to cover ***all*** the tenses listed. And to be honest I'm not sure whether that qualifies as "future perfect continuous", or whether it's a variant of "modal/conditional perfect conditional", since it's equivalent to ***would** have been hoping* (i.e. - referring to OP's supposed past state, not some future state that hasn't arisen yet).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know, "future perfect continuous" seems pretty easy: I will have been running, for example.

Comment: @Mark: I think they're all "pretty easy" in the sense that native speakers are accustomed to using and hearing all of them. I voted to close because the question as a whole is too broad. Even analysing distinctions of nuance/prevalence for *will/would have been hoping* is a question in its own right, and there will be plenty more complex and/or contentious issues in this whole question as currently posed. And I think OP just wants a brief "study prioritisation list", which imho is right up at the off-topic end of ESL-motivated questions.

Comment: Tenses are language specific, and also (to some extent) textbook specific. For instance, in English class we were taught that English has a *progressive tense* (I am sailing), while in Dutch class nobody ever listed the Dutch near-equivalent (Ik ben aan het zeilen) as a tense.

Comment: Google Ngrams (see [example](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+be+running%2C+will+have+been+running%2C+will+have+run&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3); I've checked it for several verbs) seems to say that the future perfect is uncommon, and the future perfect continuous is even less common, even in writing. But neither of these is truly rare. I don't believe spoken English differs greatly from written in this sense.

Comment: all of them. one of the many reasons english (and other languages) is hard to learn.